# How to calculate the average hashrate when ethminer reports hashrates that seem variable?

Tags: mining, hashrate, miner, ethminer

The Ethereum miner `ethminer` sometimes produces variable hashrates like:

```
miner  02:16:07.510|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #ad8608a0… : 20971520 H/s = 4194304 hashes / 0.2 s
miner  02:16:07.711|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #ad8608a0… : 83468736 H/s = 16777216 hashes / 0.201 s
miner  02:16:07.913|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #ad8608a0… : 41734368 H/s = 8388608 hashes / 0.201 s
miner  02:16:08.114|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #ad8608a0… : 83468736 H/s = 16777216 hashes / 0.201 s
miner  02:16:08.315|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #ad8608a0… : 41734368 H/s = 8388608 hashes / 0.201 s
miner  02:16:08.517|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #ad8608a0… : 83468736 H/s = 16777216 hashes / 0.201 s
miner  02:16:08.718|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #ad8608a0… : 41734368 H/s = 8388608 hashes / 0.201 s
miner  02:16:08.920|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #ad8608a0… : 83468736 H/s = 16777216 hashes / 0.201 s
```

How do you calculate the average hashrate in this case?

This situation occurs commonly when your GPUs are overclocked, or the `ethminer` parameters `--cl-local-work` and `--cl-global-work` are changed from the default settings.

**Update**

Reddit user [athropal](https://www.reddit.com/user/arthropal) has stated in [reddit.com/r/EtherMining](https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherMining/comments/4er4nu/how_to_calculate_the_average_hashrate_when/):

> The hashrate is not variable, only the reporting math is inaccurate because of the short farm-recheck time. If you look at qtminer, which uses a more effective method of getting data, it has longer periods of time to calculate the hashrate of, 2 seconds vs 0.2. The reported hashrate there is much more stable.

Comment: #1: Use newer version of ethminer. #2: Use a `--farm-recheck` value of  1000-4000 (_if using stratum_). This should smooth out your *displayed* rate. But.. The rate your miner shows and reports means nothing w/ regards to revenue. It's all about solutions. More hashrate helps more solutions of course, but the solutions reported by a pool is what you need to watch. (Meaning: Solutions found are used to determine hashrate under a given pool, normally). If farming direct/solo/getwork/http - the farm recheck should be small (100-500).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a Perl script that will calculate your average hashrate and display the important lines in your `ethminer` log files:

```
ℹ  21:19:58.840|ethminer  B-) Submitted and accepted.
✘  20:23:53.048|ethminer  FAILURE: GPU gave incorrect result!`
```

This script works on Linux and Mac OS X as the Perl interpreter is available on these platforms by default. For Windows, you may have to try Perl from [perl.org](https://www.perl.org/get.html).

Note that this hashrate is calculated when `ethminer` is calculating it's hashes, and does not include the time that `ethminer` is getting a new work package from `geth` (or the pool) or when it is submitting the results to `geth`/pool.

Copy the following lines into `$HOME/bin/calcHashrate`, and set the executable bit for this file by running the command `chmod 700 $HOME/bin/calcHashrate`.

---

**calcHashrate**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -W
use Getopt::Long;

my $DEFAULTHASHLINES = 1000;
my $DEFAULTACCEPTLINES = 4;
my $DEFAULTFAILURELINES = 4;

my ($hashlines, $acceptlines, $failurelines, $removecolour, $help);

GetOptions(
  "hashlines:i"    => \$hashlines,
  "acceptlines:i"  => \$acceptlines,
  "failurelines:i" => \$failurelines,
  "removecolour"   => \$removecolour,
  "help"           => \$help
);

die "Usage: $0 [options]\n\n" .
    " where the options are:\n" .
    "  --hashlines=x     Calculate average hashrate over the last x lines, default $DEFAULTHASHLINES\n" .
    "  --acceptlines=y   Display the last y 'accept' lines, default $DEFAULTACCEPTLINES\n" .
    "  --failurelines=z  Display the last z 'FAILURE' lines, default $DEFAULTFAILURELINES\n" .
    "  --removecolour    Don't display colour in the accept and failure lines\n" .
    "  --help            Display this help\n\n" .
    "Enjoy. BokkyPooBah 2016.\n\n" .
    "Stopped"
  if defined $help;

$hashlines = $DEFAULTHASHLINES
  unless defined $hashlines;
$acceptlines = $DEFAULTACCEPTLINES
  unless defined $acceptlines;
$failurelines = $DEFAULTFAILURELINES
  unless defined $failurelines;

my (@hashlinearray, @acceptlinearray, @failurelinearray) = ((), (), ());
while (<>) {
  if (/(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d).*:\s(\d+).*=\s(\d+).*\/\s(\d+\.\d+)/) {
    push @hashlinearray, $_;
    shift @hashlinearray
      if ($#hashlinearray >= $hashlines);
  } elsif (/accept/) {
    push @acceptlinearray, $_;
    shift @acceptlinearray
      if ($#acceptlinearray >= $acceptlines);
  } elsif (/FAILURE/) {
    push @failurelinearray, $_;
    shift @failurelinearray
      if ($#failurelinearray >= $failurelines);
  }
}

my ($totalhashes, $totalperiod) = (0, 0);
my ($lasttime) = ();
foreach (@hashlinearray) {
  if (/(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d).*:\s(\d+).*=\s(\d+).*\/\s(\d+\.\d+)/) {
    my ($time, $rate, $hashes, $period) = $_ =~ /(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d).*:\s(\d+).*=\s(\d+).*\/\s(\d+\.\d+)/;
    $totalhashes += $hashes;
    $totalperiod += $period;
    $lasttime = $time;
  }
}

foreach (@acceptlinearray) {
  s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g
    if defined $removecolour;
  print;
}

foreach (@failurelinearray) {
  s/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g
    if defined $removecolour;
  print;
}

if ($totalperiod > 0) {
  my $averagehashrate = $totalhashes / $totalperiod / 1000 / 1000;
  printf "%s %.3f MH/s\n", $lasttime, $averagehashrate;
} else {
  print "No statistics\n";
}
```

---

**Sample Usage**

```
user@Kumquat:~$ calcHashrate --help
Usage: calcHashrate [options]

 where the options are:
  --hashlines=x     Calculate average hashrate over the last x lines, default 1000
  --acceptlines=y   Display the last y 'accept' lines, default 4
  --failurelines=z  Display the last z 'FAILURE' lines, default 4
  --removecolour    Don't display colour in the accept and failure lines
  --help            Display this help

Enjoy. BokkyPooBah 2016.

Stopped at ./calcHashrate line 18.
```

Run the script with the default settings, calculating the average hashrate over the last 1,000 lines, show up to 4 `accept` lines and show up to 4 `FAILURE` lines. The line at the bottom shows the last hashrate time and the average hashrate in megahashes per second.

```
user@Kumquat:~$ calcHashrate logs/ethminer.log --removecolour
  ℹ  21:24:12.221|ethminer  B-) Submitted and accepted.
  ℹ  21:24:14.671|ethminer  B-) Submitted and accepted.
  ℹ  21:24:17.519|ethminer  B-) Submitted and accepted.
  ℹ  21:24:30.835|ethminer  B-) Submitted and accepted.
  ✘  18:11:00.367|ethminer  FAILURE: GPU gave incorrect result!
  ✘  18:41:12.725|ethminer  FAILURE: GPU gave incorrect result!
  ✘  20:03:32.135|ethminer  FAILURE: GPU gave incorrect result!
  ✘  20:23:53.048|ethminer  FAILURE: GPU gave incorrect result!
21:25:04.239 62.619 MH/s
```

Run the script to just display the hashrate over the last 1,000 hashrate lines.

```
user@Kumquat:~$ calcHashrate ethminer.log --acceptlines=0 --failurelines=0
21:25:04.239 62.619 MH/s
```